# HTML flexbox custom spacing with space-between creating an addition item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I just playing around with HTML and try to make a ToDo List. 
My HTML looks like this:

```html
<h1>To Do List</h1>

<div class="header">
  <input type="text" placeholder="New Task..." name="task" id="task" class="task" autocomplete="off">
  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>

<ul id="myUL"></ul>

<script src="script/js.js"></script>
```

This is my start page

[image]

After I added a new task, i have this

[image]

This is one `li`-element. So I added a `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`. So the text is on the left and the close-button on the right.

Now I can also check the task I already completed. This looks like this.

[image]

Because I create this checked-icon I now have three elements in my `li`-element. So the task-name is centered. What I want now is to have spacing between the checked-symbol and the task-name. The close-button should be still on the right side.

I played around with `justify-content` for my `li`-elements and the `.close`-class. I thought I can make the `li`-element `flex-start` and the `.close`-class `flex-end`. 
This is what I come up with:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve my goal with flexboxes? If yes, how can I do it?
Here is the full css-file, I played around for some time, so many parts from the css are unneccessary, please ignore them.

```
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

body{
    background: #F2994A;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #F2C94C, #F2994A);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #F2C94C, #F2994A); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;

}

h1{
  color: white;
}

.header{
    width: 40%;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.task{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
}

.addBtn{
    text-align: right;
    border: none;
    background: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
}

ul{
    padding-top: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 40%;
    align-content: center;


  }
  li{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #2f4f4f;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }

  .close {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    align-content: right;
    justify-content: space-end;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;

  }

  .close:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  ul li:hover{
      background: #ddd;

  }

  /* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
ul li.checked {
    background: #888;
    color: #fff;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  /* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
ul li.checked::before {
    content: '';
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    align-content: center;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 15px;
    width: 7px;
  }
```

**EDIT:**
Working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lo0cd6qv/).

Comment: _“My HTML looks like this”_ - that contains only a naked `ul` carcass, but no actual list items, or any of what you put into them. You did not post your script, so we don’t know what structure you are actually dealing with now. Please provide a _proper_ [mre].

Comment: @misorude I add the li-elements with my java script. I added the script.

Comment: With that I can add new items (if I copy&paste stuff around, to create a runable example from your snippets - please _you_ do that next time, either by using the Stack Snippet functionality here, or by providing an external example in a jsfiddle or something), but I still have no idea how to make the check mark appear.

Comment: @misorude: very strage...You should be able to click the task if you hover over it, and the mark appears, I try to reproduce it with jsfiddle. Sorry for that

Comment: @misorude I added a working demo on jsfiddle. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Aha, elements with default cursor are clickable :-) I think it would make most sense if you did not insert this check mark as a pseudo element, but used a `span` that always exists for that, same as with the X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a demo with basic styles that can match your task list. Please check the example

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.task {
  color: #666;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}


.task.checked {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.task.checked::before {
    content: '';
    border-color: #666;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    align-content: center;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 15px;
    width: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 8px;
}

.task-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.close {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">

<ul class="my-3">
  <li class="task checked">
    <h4 class="task-title">Task Item</h4>
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
  </li>
  <li class="task">
    <h4 class="task-title">Task Item</h4>
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
  </li>
  <li class="task">
    <h4 class="task-title">Task Item</h4>
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

And your demo fiddle updated (https://jsfiddle.net/rhythm19/pa9ouhmd/).

Answer (score 1):

I added `margin-right: 1em;` to the `ul li.checked::before` bit in your demo and got spacing.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed display flex and text-align :center and justify content from ul and li 
here is your file of css and html

```css
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

body{
    background: #F2994A;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #F2C94C, #F2994A);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #F2C94C, #F2994A); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;

}

h1{
  color: white;
}

.header{
    width: 40%;
    background-color: white;
    
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.task{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
}

.addBtn{
    text-align: right;
    border: none;
    background: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
}

ul{
   
    list-style: none;
    width: 40%;
    align-content: center;


  }
  li{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #2f4f4f;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .close {
    float: right;


  }
  .text{
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .close:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  ul li:hover{
      background: #ddd;

  }

  /* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
ul li.checked {
    background: #888;
    color: #fff;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  /* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
ul li.checked::before {
    content: '';
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    align-content: center;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 15px;
    width: 7px;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="this.css">
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<h1>To Do List</h1>

<div class="header">    
    <input type="text" placeholder="New Task..." name="task" id="task" class="task" autocomplete="off">
    <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>

    <ul id="myUL">
     <li class="myLi">
      <span><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
      <span class="text">Text</span>
      <span class="close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
     </li>
    </ul>



<script src="script/js.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```